MS Graph: adding team owners/members through groups or teams
I'm in the progress of making a coupling between our  SIS (school information system) and Teams us MS Graph. In the past we used SDS for that, but that is going into a direction we don't like. Not the discussion for now. This is:
Currently at the point where I have to make a decision on how to add owners/members to the teams I create. Teams being specialized groups I seem to have 2 options:

with the groups add member/owner option
with the teams add member/owner option

It seems that by adding them through the groups option there can be a 24 hour delay before the user is actually added to the team, and one of the team users will have to have been online in the Teams desktop app. A bit of a hazzle it seems.
Reading that I'm inclined to add them using the teams method.
But are there other considerations that I'm missing?
Peter

There are also different security permissions needed - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions . Other than that, why not try the Teams option and see if it works out ok?

Not much response, so did some more investigation on my own. For what it's worth:
Yes offcourse you need different permissions for the different methods used. My question was not on that level. More like seeking for knowledge. One can get the permissions needed from the API docs.
Team being specialized groups they have a lot in common. You can indeed add owners and members using the groups API. But you'll have to take into considiration that:

An owner should also be a member. Adding an owner costs you 2 separate transactions.
A group membership is translated to a team membership by a background process. This process can take up to 24 hours to complete.
This "translation" process is only started when one of the team users has been online in team using the desktop app.
You can add up to 20 members at a time You could use batched JSON to do this, but the batch can also only have 20 transactions.
A 1 second delay is suggested after you add a group member.

On the other hand:
When you add a member through the teams API the member is added with a role. That way an ower can be added with one transaction.
The team API also imposes a 20 users limit, but there is also a method to add users in bulk. Using this method you can add up to 200 users in one transaction.
I did not find any information as to delays when adding team members.
For the purpose of maintaining teams for classes (in an educational institute) the methos of adding members using the team methods seems to be the better option.
On a side note (not in the original question but perhaps of interest):
Creating a group and turning it into an educational team (with the educationClass template) does not work. The group has to be associated with a class. The only way, I found, you can do this is by using the create class method in the education API. That way the associated group is created automaticly.
